# Pandas expand rows from list data available in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, recommendation-engine

**I have a data frame like this in pandas**

[image]

The output shows **...** which i highlighted here and it shows first 5 rows and last 5 rows. **But i want to get first 25 rows** as my results and **download that output as a txt file.**

Answer (score 1):

You should use

[pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas-set-option) to achieve your goal

You could run below command:

```
import pandas
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # list all rows
```

or

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', 25)  # list max to max 25 rows
```

Comment: ('display.max_rows', None) shows all the rows but ('display.max_rows', 25) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = data.iloc[0:25]
file.to_csv('data.txt')
```